# Not able to override phtml file

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, php-5.4

I am trying to override phtml file inside theme module. Below is my code

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Netsmartz_Welcomemessage" setup_version="1.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

Default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="messages">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::messages.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

I have placed messages.phtml file in app\code\Netsmartz\Welcomemessage\view\frontend\templates\theme path.

Any idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In argument (default.xml) you have specify your new phtml file. But you have given original phtml file. Instead of Magento_Theme you have to use **Netsmartz_Welcomemessage::theme/messages.phtml**

```
<referenceBlock name="messages">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Netsmartz_Welcomemessage::theme/messages.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the template file path in the  `default.xml` file like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="messages">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Netsmartz_Welcomemessage::messages.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```